# ANOVA with continuous time signal

Tags: anova, continuous-data, manova

I have a very large data set of a continuous time signal as measured force(N). I want to do a 4-way ANOVA to compare 12 groups in this data (or compare the signals).

My question is, how should I convert signals to discrete values to compare them?

I looked on the internet and saw using Median split and ANACOA but they are not appropriate for this data signals. While signals' standard deviation are too small in one condition, in another one it is huge(like a sinusoidal signal).I think Median split and ANACOA are not good choices.

I also looked at ANOVA on EEG signals. I don't have any specifications like alpha or beta waves. I not sure if I should use the entropy.

There are [other papers](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016794730300269X) that might be helpful but I am not sure... I am using MATLAB for the analysis.